# bsd_glob behaving differently on different machines

Tags: regex, perl

I am using `bsd_glob` to get a list of files matching a regular expression for file path. My perl utility is working on `RHEL`, but not on `Suse 11/AIX/Solarix`, for the exact same set of files and the same regular expression. I googled for any limitations of `bsd_glob`, but couldn't find much information. Can someone point what's wrong?

Below is the regular expression for the file path I am searching for:

```
/datafiles/data_one/level_one/*/DATA*
```

I need all files beginning with DATA, in any directory present under 'level_one'.
This works perfectly on my `RHEL` box, but not on any other `Unix` and `Suse Linux`.

Below is the code snipped where I am using `bsd_glob`

```
foreach my $file (bsd_glob ( "$fileName", GLOB_ERR )) {
    if ($fileName =~ /[[:alnum:]]\*\/\*$/) {
        next if -d $file;
        $fileList{$file} = $permissions;
        $total++;
    }   
    elsif ($fileName =~ /[[:alnum:]]\*$/) {
        $fileList{$file} = $permissions;
        $total++;
    }   
    else {
        $fileList{$file} = $permissions;
        $total++;
    }   
}
```

In this case where I am facing the issue, `/datafiles/data_one/level_one/*/DATA*` is being passed to `bsd_glob`. I am creating a map (`$fileList`) of files that are returned by `bsd_glob` based on the regular expression I am passing to it. `$permissions` is a predefined value.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: That's not a regular expression. At least, I hope it isn't!

Comment: the part before the 'star' is fixed, I need to match anything after that fixed part, and anything after that containing DATA*

Comment: Show us a complete (but short) working code example that demonstrates  the problem.

Comment: Why are you using `bsd_glob` specifically here? It doesn't look like it's doing anything above and beyond 'standard'?

Comment: Also - what is `$filename` set to? That pattern you specified?

Comment: yes, $filename is the pattern I have mentioned

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here looks to be that you're confusing glob patterns and regular expressions.

```
/[[:alnum:]]\*\/\*$/
/[[:alnum:]]\*$/
```

You're looking for a file called `*` with that, under a directory containing a literal `*`.

Whilst that is technically possible it's really very strange. And simply cannot *ever* match the patterns your `glob` should find.

Do you perhaps mean:

```
m,\w+.*/.*$,
```

(different delimiter for clarity)

Also - why are you using `bsd_glob` specifically? From [`File::Glob`](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Glob.html):

> Since v5.6.0, Perl's CORE::glob() is implemented in terms of bsd_glob(). Note that they don't share the same prototype--CORE::glob() only accepts a single argument. Due to historical reasons, CORE::glob() will also split its argument on whitespace, treating it as multiple patterns, whereas bsd_glob() considers them as one pattern. But see :bsd_glob under EXPORTS, below.

Comment:

> I used bsd_glob instead of glob as there was slight difference in the way it works on different UNIX platforms. Specifically, for the above mentioned pattern, on some UNIX platforms, it didn't return a file having exact name 'DATA', and only returned files with something appended to DATA.

I'm a little surprised at that, as they should be implementing the same mechanisms and the same POSIX standard on globbing. Is there any chance there's a permissions related problem instead?

But otherwise you could perhaps try *not* using `glob` to do the heavy lifting, and instead just compare the file name to a bunch of regular expressions. (Although note - REs have very different syntax)

```
foreach my $file ( glob('/datafiles/data_one/level_one/*/*') ) {
    next unless $filename =~ m,DATA\w+$,;
}
```

Comment: I used `bsd_glob` instead of `glob` as there was slight difference in the way it works on different UNIX platforms.  Specifically, for the above mentioned pattern, on some UNIX platforms, it didn't return a file having exact name 'DATA', and only returned files with something appended to DATA.

Comment: my main concern is, the program works correctly for the exact same set of input on one platform, while it doesn't on another. The perl version used on both the systems is the same.

Comment: The `bsd_glob` flag you have set will cause it to bail out if you hit an error. And chance that's happening? I also can't see much value in your 3 matches - the regexes don't look like they work, so you only ever run the last code block.

Comment: Hmm, that's quite odd, as that doc suggests that they're both using the same mechanisms to do the globbing in the first place.